# Sort list in pandas series by length of string

Tags: python, list, pandas, sorting, series

I want to sort a list in a dataframe based on the length of the strings (longest first)

```
brand       serie
&tradition  [&tradition flowerpot, &tradition spinning pen, &tradition test]
Dove        [dove deeply nourishing, dove men+care]
Adidas      [adidas ace, adidas gel]
Vasaline    [vaseline advanced repair, vaseline men]
Boska       [boska dutch, boska test2, boska testing]
```

I want the result to look something like this:

```
brand       serie
.....       ......
Boska       [boska testing, boska dutch, boska test2]
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.apply` with `sorted`:

```
def sorter(x):
    return sorted(x, key=len, reverse=True)

df['serie'] = df['serie'].apply(sorter)
```